# textChangedListener not executing asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, textchanged

I'm writing this app that fetches movie information from rottentomatoes API. I'm using a client to do the parsing and httprequests.

First i tried setting up a searchview, but since im using framents (FragmentNavigationDrawer) it's not an option.

The next best thing. EditText with a ListPopupWindow.

I set up textchangelistener so that when i start typing stuff into the given edittext(search) it SHOULD execute asynctask(using the edittext input as a searchword for the api request). However, nothing happens. Not a thing. There aint single line of red text in logcat, app wont crash, no nothing. So im turning to you god-tier coders at stackoverflow.

The fragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment{
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
EditText search;
List<Movie> result = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private MovieAdapter adpt;
MovieSearch searchTask = new MovieSearch();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment, container, false);
    search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchBox2);
    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getActivity());
    adpt = new MovieAdapter(new ArrayList<Movie>(), getActivity());
    searchTask = new MovieSearch();

    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(adpt);
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(search);
    listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);

    listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3){

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3){

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable){
            searchTask.cancel(true);


            String input = search.getText().toString();
            searchTask.execute(input);

        }
    });

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment, container, false);

}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // detect the view that was "clicked"
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.addToCollection: //just a placeholder
            break;
        }
    }

    private class MovieSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Movie>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adpt.setMovieList(result);
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... params){
            Log.e("Status", "Entered thread");
            String input = (params[0]);
            JTomato jtomato = new JTomato("jf6cykts4sybqrex3dkjd7uq");
            jtomato.setPage_limit(1);
            jtomato.searchMovie(input, result, 0);
            if (isCancelled())
            {
                 //Notify your activity that you had canceled the task
                return (null);
            }



            return result;
        }




    }



}
```

Comment: Please place "Log.e("Status","Entered thread");" in do in background of your async and check if it enters or not

Comment: How do you know? It looks like you are always returning `null` from `doInBackground()`. And you can't relaunch a task like that. You need to create a new instance of the task each time. `MovieSearch searchTask.execute();` Besides all of that, this is not how you want to be doing it. Trying to cancel and relaunch a task each time they type a letter?

Comment: I must have misunderstood something about cancelling tasks, i the status needs to be changed and executed afterwards(im either retarded and/or tired). How do you suppose i should do the searching? Is there a way to start a search when the "enter-key" is pressed on keyboard? This search is only for find a movie. After that, im adding a different asyncTask wich gets details from that said movie.

Comment: First of all, return a `List<Moviess>` from `doInBackground()`  instead of returning null. Second, make a "Search" button and execute the MovieSearch  AsyncTask when the button is clicked, instead of each time a letter is typed.

Comment: Try moving all your logic from onTextChanged to afterTextChanged and also initiate "searchTask" with new MovieSearch each time

Answer (score 1):

You are never creating and instance of the AsyncTask MovieSearch searchTask it is always null.

add this code
`searchTask = new MovieSearch();`

before calling

`searchTask.execute()`;